# Django. How to use filters in include with clause

Tags: django

I have link component which i include like that

```
{% include "components/item_link.html" with href="{{ title | lower | slugify }}" %}
```

It renders with href equal to `{{ title | lower | slugify }}` instead of properly filtered title value (string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add extra curly brackets (`{{ … }}`), but just pass this as:

```
{% include "components/item_link.html" with href=title|lower|slugify %}
```

Comment: How do I prepend the result value, say to start with `#`?

Comment: @Herrgott: with the standard Django template tags, I don't think you can. Can't you use `#{{ href }}` in the `item_link.html` template?

Comment: @Herrgott: an alternative is of course to write your own custom template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: no, i have to prepend # in upper call, because there can be external link too

Comment: @Herrgott: then I think you will have to write a custom filter. Something that is basically the reverse of `add:`, where it adds the argument to the object, and not the object to the argument..

Comment: `{% with t=title|lower|slugify %}  .....  "#"|add:t   ......  {% endwith %}` worked for me